# Keep WinUI 3 (Windows App SDK) window always at bottom

Tags: c#, xaml, .net-core, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

I have the following window using Windows App SDK 1.1.5 and WinUI 3, I want to keep it always at the bottom, just above the desktop, `m_AppWindow.MoveInZOrderAtBottom();` moves it to the very bottom as I intended, but once it is pressed it comes back to the foreground.

How can I prevent it from coming to the foreground once clicked? I suppose it may be related to the HWND handle.

```cs
using Microsoft.UI;
using Microsoft.UI.Windowing;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using System;
using WinRT.Interop;

namespace Widgets {
  public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window {

    private AppWindow m_AppWindow;

    public MainWindow() {
      this.InitializeComponent();

      m_AppWindow = GetAppWindowForCurrentWindow();
      m_AppWindow.MoveInZOrderAtBottom();
    }

    private AppWindow GetAppWindowForCurrentWindow() {
      IntPtr hWnd = WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this);
      WindowId wndId = Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(hWnd);
      return AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(wndId);
    }
  }
}
```

This is just a slightly modified `MainWindow.cs` from the visual studio `Blank App, Packaged (WinUI 3 in Desktop) C#` template.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it this way.

```cs
public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private AppWindow m_AppWindow;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        m_AppWindow = GetAppWindowForCurrentWindow();
        m_AppWindow.Changed += M_AppWindow_Changed;
    }

    private void M_AppWindow_Changed(AppWindow sender, AppWindowChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.DidZOrderChange is true)
        {
            m_AppWindow.MoveInZOrderAtBottom();
        }
    }

    private AppWindow GetAppWindowForCurrentWindow()
    {
        IntPtr hWnd = WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this);
        WindowId wndId = Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(hWnd);
        return AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(wndId);
    }
}
```